# How to return rows of a dataframe based on the minimum value of a cluster

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a 400,7 dataframe made of the following columns

```
columns=['cluster', 'p', 'q', 'AIC', 'BIC', 'ar_params', 'ma_params']
```

I wish to return a dataframe containing one row for each cluster corresponding to the minimum value of 'BIC' for that specific cluster.

I tried

```
order_aic_bic.groupby('cluster')['BIC'].min()
```

which returns the minimum 'BIC' value of 'BIC' for each cluster,

but I am looking to produce a 4 by 6 dataframe (there are four clusters)with the following columns/values

```
[cluster, BIC, p, q, ar_params, ma_params]
```

for the p, q, ar_params, ma_params corresponding to the minimum BIC value for each of the four clusters.

Thank you.

Comment: you could join (pd.concat) the 4x2 df you obtained with the original using cluster and bic as keys for the join

Answer (score 0):

You can sort the dataframe by the bic variable and call `head` after the `groupby`

```
df.sort_values('BIC').groupby('cluster').head(1)
```